# How do I deploy an individual Step Function without re-deploying the entire stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I'm rather new to AWS Lambda and Step Functions, and the serverless framework in general. From my understanding, we can deploy an entire service via CloudFormation using the command `serverless deploy`. However to save time, we can just update specific Lambda functions we have made changes to, by using `serverless deploy function -f myFunction`.

Is there an equivalent of this for Step Functions so that I don't have to redeploy the entire service whenever I only make a change to the Step Function? I have already tried `serverless deploy function -f myStepFunction` but I simply get a Serverless Error that it does not exist in the Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the step functions plugin, using this you first do `sls deploy` which will deploy the state machine for you.
Now if you don't change the state machine diagram, then you can simply do `sls deploy -f functionName` to deploy the individual functions.

Comment: Does this mean that as long my state machine diagram changes, I will have to do a `sls deploy` to redeploy the entire service (which sadly takes 15min on my hardware)? Is there a possible workaround to only re-deploy the step function without re-deploying the entire service?

Comment: @AmehPls if you make changes to the state machine then it has to be a redeployment unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Just to tag along, we've got a pull request open on the step functions plugin to do this.

Comment: Not works for version 3.34.0